# Python threading - with limited threads, iterate over n number of Items

Tags: python

Here is an example read from IBM python threading tutorial. I was going through this URL (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2
import time

hosts = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://amazon.com",
"http://ibm.com", "http://apple.com"]

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
"""Threaded Url Grab"""
def __init__(self, queue):
  threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  self.queue = queue

def run(self):
  while True:
    #grabs host from queue
    host = self.queue.get()

    #grabs urls of hosts and prints first 1024 bytes of page
    url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
    print url.read(1024)

    #signals to queue job is done
    self.queue.task_done()

start = time.time()
def main():

#spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
for i in range(5):
  t = ThreadUrl(queue)
  t.setDaemon(True)
  t.start()

#populate queue with data   
  for host in hosts:
    queue.put(host)

#wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
queue.join()

main()
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

The example here works perfectly. I have been looking for a slightly different modification. Here there are known number of URL's , like for example 5. used range(5) in for loop to iterate over the URL's and process it.

What if, i want to use only '5' threads to process 1000 URL's? so when a thread completes, the completed URL should be removed from queue and new URL needs to be added to queue. But all these should happen by using the same thread.

I can check ,

```
if self.queue.task_done():
    return host
```

This is the only way i can check if the URL is processed successfully or not. Once returned , i should remove URL from the queue. and add a new URL to queue. How to implement this using queue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That code will already do what you describe. If you put 1000 items into the queue instead of 5, they will be processed by those same 5 threads - each one will take an item from the queue, process it, then take a new one as long as there are items left in the queue.

Comment: No its not working. I checked again. The thread used is 5 and the thread is not collecting the host from the queue again and again. so once the task is done, the thread will exit.